# Is there a limit to the number of applications I can own?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I run my own blogging platform and have a number of clients who we design blogs for. I want to setup a unique facebook application for each of them as they all use their own domain names. I got partway through creating individual apps this morning and am now being told I can't create any more. I managed to create 12 so far.

Is this a physical limit to the number of apps I can own or is it just I've created too many in a short space of time? I have around 60 clients and would like an app for each of them.

Can anyone advise me please?

S

Comment: I think it’s rather a time limit than a limit to the overall amount of apps you can create. (If there was a limit on the general amount, at least I think it’ll be way higher then 12.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe ... I'll wait a few hours and see if it lets me create more. Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

This has to be a time thing.  I have created over 120 facebook applications.